# xrandr right-of with y offset

Tags: xrandr

Is it possible to use right-of with offset in y direction? I have two displays and I want the second monitor to be right of the first and 550 pixels below, like:

```
-----------------
|               |
|     HDMI-2    |--------------
|               ||            |
-----------------|    eDP-1   |
                 |            |
                 --------------
```

Currently I'm setting the position with

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --pos 1680x550
```

but often I have a third display and I think, `right-of` works best for different configurations. With third monitor it looks like:

```
----------------------------------
|               ||               |
|    HDMI-1     ||    HDMI-2     |--------------
|               ||               ||            |
----------------------------------|    eDP-1   |
                                  |            |
                                  --------------
```

Comment: did you make it work?

Comment: No, I still use a fixed position and manually change the position when the configuration changes.